# Windows not booting up on VM Fusion. Need to get a file off of windows

Tags: vmware

I am a pilot that has my logbook on the windows side of my iMac. Windows has been failing to boot up gives me an 000021a error every time. I have tried booting in last known good configuration and is safe mode but nothing gets windows to boot. I am trying to find out if I can access my logbook file even though windows is not booting. Anyone with any words of advice?!

Comment: Is Windows on a NTFS partition on your iMac? What version of Mac OS are you running on the HFS+ partition?

Comment: Is it a bootcamp partition?

Comment: It is on a bootcamp partition. I want to say that I could get a bootable windows cd and be fine...I think.

Comment: Can you give us the output of the `disktutil list` command? Open a Terminal window, run that command, paste it in to your answer. You should be able to read from that bootcamp partition from OS X and at least save your data before you try repairing windows on it. Also: have you tried rebooting your Mac and just booting in to the Windows partition (i.e. not using Fusion to run Windows off the partition)?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is as follows:

1. create a new VM
2. Install Windows on that VM
3. Shutdown the New VM
4. In the New VM preferences, add the .vmdk for your old VM as a secondary drive on the new VM
5. Start up your new VM and you old drive should now be visible as a secondary drive

Browse to the files you need to retrieve, copy to the new VM and you are done, all bar reversing the above and deleting the old VM

Comment: With one minor correction, this might work well: the disk to add to the new VM isn't the old VM's `.vmdk` file, it's the bootcamp partition for Windows (his old VM used that partition). This is probably simpler than trying to read the NTFS bootcamp partition from OS X (which is where I was going with my comment and request on the question).

Comment: True and thx for the clarification, my original thought was just to install MacFuse and see if he could browse the data that way.

Comment: Yea, I was going to give detailed NTFS-reading instructions once he updated with the `diskutil` output. Let's see if he comes back...